# Kerberos Ticket Expiring with MSSQL JDBC connection

Tags: sql-server, windows, jdbc, kerberos

We are using JDBC to connect to MSSQL server with Kerberos for a java app running on windows.

Application Server Windows Server Windows 2012 R2
MSSQL version Microsoft Sql server 2016 (SP1)

We have two servers one is App server say A and another is DB server say B.

Our app works fine for 7 days until the kerberos token is present and then when token expires it doesn't work until we restart the app.

We are using String.

String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://MyServer;integratedSecurity=true;"

In our case, its 2 hop where we see ticket gets renewed on server A but when DB bulk insert trys to get file from Server A, it fails with Access denied issue since token is expired.

Can anyone provide any comments?

Error message:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot bulk load because the file "\files\temp\data\csv\PROD_FILE.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.). at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)

Thanks,

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and include the full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: So... you know that your **session** will fail after 7 days, you know which error message to trap, but you are too lazy to trap the message and then { close session using stale ticket ; reopen session with current ticket ; retry operation }

Comment: Hi,  We are trying to keep renewing the sessions every 24 hours to avoid this problem.   Trapping the error message is not straightforward since we are application developer and this Kerberos authentication works internally(No code was ever written to use this) . We did work with our windows admin teams to enable more window event alerts but not much of details present there.  Will update here if our current solution works.